# node.js worker crashes (SIGKILL) for no apparent reason

Tags: node.js

I have a number of workers handling http-connections (express). The server handles many simultaneous connections at once. Since large files are being proxied the connections can be relatively long.

No exceptions are being thrown at all. How could I track down the cause?

Thank you.

node.js v0.10.25
Linux version 2.6.32-5-amd64 (Debian 2.6.32-48squeeze1)

Comment: Is it running in a virtualmachine?

Comment: No virtual machine. The master process is controlled by `forever`. Also the master process does not die. Only the workers crash with that signal once they handled a number of connections.

Comment: What do you mean? you have `forever -> processA` and `processA` dies or `forever -> processA -> processB` and `processB` dies?, Which server are you running?

Comment: processB dies. No additional software is involved that could cause the signal. Interesting is that processB only dies after some time - usually after around 6k connections.

Comment: If I'm right and that the number is quite constant, it is possible that somewhere in the code there is a magic number to kill the workers after 6k connections. I believe `gevent` workers in python die after 1k connections. While I still think that using `SIGKILL` isn't appropriate. It should use `SIGTERM`.

Answer (score 0):

SIGKILL is a signal that is sent to a process to kill it immediatly, it is possible and likely that an external process is killing nodejs. There are many reasons why it could happen but it's unlikely that nodejs is crashing because it receives a SIGKILL signal.

In case of running a Server with Workers, It might happen simply naturally. Without knowing which server you are running, it is hard to say if it's a problem or if everything is fine. I know that some webserver in python do that to free memory. As the webservers might naturally leak memory, it is better to kill the workers and start new workers than having to handle GC etc. It's quite possible that if you have big files, the main server is smart enough to see that the subprocess are either leaking memory or become unresponsive while doing a big GC.

The main server will then kill the workers and start a new worker.